# does anyone knows how to setup .nettiers with sharepoint 2010 please?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, .nettiers

does anyone knows how to setup .nettiers with sharepoint 2010 please?

Answer (score 0):

nettiers looks like a code templating engine for development, it reads database schemas to build your code model, and maybe an application layer.

Directly reading from the sharepoint database is not supported, so im not sure how useful nettiers will be. SPSite/SPWeb/SPList/SPListItem is what you should be using.

I would recommend initially just staying with Visual Studio 2010 for you development.